# Transfomar str a formato de diccionario en python

Tags: python, estructuras-de-datos, diccionarios

Quisiera convertir este texto de tipo `str` a dicccionario de python,como se puede ver, todos los indices o llaves están sin comillas, por ello no lo puedo hacer directo un json.loads, he intentado haciendo `result_data = dict(json.loads(data))`, sin embargo el problema son las comillas

```
data = '{data:{feedback:{id:"ZmVlZGJhY2s6MTAxNjAyMzY4MzgwNzg4MzY=",is_eligible_for_real_time_updates:false,subscription_target_id:"10160236838078836",owning_profile:{__typename:"Page",id:"71263708835"},num_localized_comment_orderings:3,unfiltered_comment_count:{is_empty:false},comment_count:{total_count:1},i18n_comment_count:"1",url:"https://www.facebook.com/elcomercio.pe/posts/10160236838078836",i18n_reaction_count:"7",important_reactors:{nodes:[]},reaction_count:{count:7},reaction_display_config:{reaction_display_strategy:"NONE"},viewer_actor:null,viewer_feedback_reaction_info:null,i18n_share_count:"0",share_count:{count:0},share_fbid:"10160236838078836",reactors:{count:7,is_empty:false},top_reactions:{edges:[{reaction_count:6,node:{key:1,id:"1635855486666999",localized_name:"Me gusta",reaction_type:"LIKE"},i18n_reaction_count:"6"},{reaction_count:1,node:{key:2,id:"1678524932434102",localized_name:"Me encanta",reaction_type:"LOVE"},i18n_reaction_count:"1"}]},associated_video:null,video_view_count:null,video_view_count_reduced:null,total_video_posts:null,video_post_view_count:null,page_private_reply:null,seen_by_count:{count:null},comment_share_context:null,political_figure_data:null,associated_group:null,display_comments_count:{count:1},comments_disabled_notice:{ranges:[],text:"Se desactivaron los comentarios para esta publicación."},can_viewer_comment:false,comment_composer_placeholder:"Escribe un comentario…",toplevel_comment_count:{count:1},display_comments:{after_count:1,before_count:0,count:1,edges:[],is_initially_expanded:false,page_size:10,reply_comment_order:"RANKED_REPLIES",should_render_composer_preemptively:true,comment_order:"RANKED_THREADED",page_info:{end_cursor:null,has_next_page:true,has_previous_page:false,start_cursor:null}},can_viewer_react:false,supported_reactions:[{key:1,id:null},{key:2,id:null},{key:4,id:null},{key:3,id:null},{key:7,id:null},{key:8,id:null}],feedback_typers:{other_count:0},default_comment_ordering:"ranked_threaded",localized_comment_orderings:[{description:"Se muestran los comentarios de amigos y los que tienen más interacciones en primer lugar.",title:"Más relevantes",value:"RANKED_THREADED"},{description:"Se muestran todos los comentarios. Los comentarios más recientes aparecerán en primer lugar.",title:"Más recientes",value:"RECENT_ACTIVITY"},{description:"Se muestran todos los comentarios, incluido el posible spam. Los comentarios más relevantes aparecerán en primer lugar.",title:"Todos los comentarios",value:"RANKED_UNFILTERED"}]}},extensions:{is_final:true}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes solucionar con `re.sub`:

```
result_data = re.sub(r'(?<=[{,])(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', data)

result_data = json.loads(result_data)
```

Este patrón regex se descompone así:

`(?<=[{,])`: La palabra está precedida por los caracteres `{` o `,`

`(\w+)`: La palabra que buscamos. `\w` hace match con cualquier caracter unicode.

`(?=:)`: La palabra está seguida de `:`

Adicional, si quieres imprimir el json en un formato legible, puedes usar esto:

```
print(json.dumps(result_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Es una solución bien hecha, muchas gracias Jose

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado de la siguiente forma:

```
result_data = json.loads(data.replace('https:', '<----->').replace('{', '{"').replace(',',',"').replace(':', '":').replace(',"{', '{').replace('}{', '},{').replace('<----->', 'https:').replace('," ', ','))
```

Gracias